# How can simulate restart action in Android Emulator?

Tags: android

I order to test  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`, I hope to  simulate restart action in Android Emulator.

How can I do? Thanks!

**And more**

If I hope to test whether `setPersisted(true)` work after I restart phone in  Android Emulator, how can I do?

```
val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(mContext.getInteger(R.integer.JobID), ComponentName(mContext, RestoreService::class.java))
                        .setPeriodic(interval)
                        .setPersisted(true)
                        .build()
```

**Added:**

The following is myAndroidManifest.xml file.

Which one is correct between Code A and Code B by your answer?

or both Code A and Code are wrong?

**Code A**

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n info.dodata.mirror/ui.UIApp
```

**Code B**

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n info.dodata.mirror/bll.BootReceiver
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.dodata.mirror">

    <application
        android:name="ui.UIApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="ui.UIMain" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="ui.UIAbout">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ui.UIAbout" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver android:name="bll.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general this ADB command will send any broadcast and you can catch with debugger:

```
adb shell am activity/service/broadcast -a ACTION -c CATEGORY -n NAME
```

Here is general boot broadcast sending:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n package_name/class_name
```

Based on your manifest, first add to manifest receiver `enabled` and `exported` this :

```
<receiver
        android:name="bll.BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
```

Example with your classes and manifest, ADB call should look like this:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n info.dodata.mirror/bll.BootReceiver
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please see "And more" section in my modified question?  If I hope to test whether `setPersisted(true)` work after I restart phone in Android Emulator, how can I do?

Comment: Thanks! Would you please see "Added" section in my modified question? About how to write  package_name/class_name

Comment: I've updated my answer with example, also tested on my PC. Concerning setPersisted question, it is another topic and another question